# Using Dispatch Function to Conditionally Render Components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-audio-api, use-context, use-reducer

So I've just refactored an app created in react using useContext/useReducer in order to manage the state better. I'm having a great time and have managed to get the dispatch function to work with bits you have to select.
HOWEVER. When it comes to conditionally rendering the start/stop button, I'm flummoxed. In my reducer function I have the following:

```
const redFunc = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case "play": {
  return {
    ...state,
    isPlaying: true,
  };
}
case "stop": {
  return {
    ...state,
    isPlaying: false,
  };
}
```

Which is passed down via React.createContext() to the components. The thing is, I don't really understand where to put the dispatch function in order to get isPlaying to actually change. Here is my start/stop button:

```
  <input
        id="on-off"
        type="button"
        value={isPlaying ? "stop" : "start"}
        onClick={() => togglePlay()}
      />
```

So somewhere, I think I need to put this line of code in, as I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
dispatch(isPlaying ? { type: "stop" } : { type: "start" });
```

Here it is in my togglePlay() function (which is definitely wrong as it doesn't work...):

```
  const togglePlay = () => {
if (isPlaying) {
  audioContextRef.current.suspend();
} else {
  audioContextRef.current.resume();
}
dispatch(isPlaying ? { type: "stop" } : { type: "start" });
};
```

I feel like there's something fundamental I'm missing about the dispatch function but I can't figure it out, and I've spent SUCH a long time on it that I'm crying tears of Reacty sadness. Everything was wonderful when I could use `useState()`...

Help...?

Comment: You need to decide which one you want to use: "play" or "start", because the reducer doesn't know anything about  "start".

Comment: Of course I do. I'm a fool. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Now you know why you should use constants instead of magic strings :) The rest is working well now?

Comment: Everything's working perfectly, thank you very much! Out of interest - what do you mean by magic strings? Should I assign the values in the objects within the dispatch function to variables?

Comment: You can also dispatch an action with type "toggle" and let your reducer figure out whether to start or stop.